# How to obtain normal subgroups of SL(2,Z) from normal subgroups of PSL(2,Z)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, modular-group

When I look for a classification of the normal subgroups of $SL(2,Z)$, I found that people tend to only study $PSL(2,Z)=SL(2,Z)/\{1,-1\}$'s subgroups or normal subgroups, as far as I know Morris Newman studied $PSL(2,Z)$'s normal subgroups classification systematically . So now **the question is how do we get normal subgroups of $SL(2,Z)$ from normal subgroups of $PSL(2,Z)$** (I don't know if this problem is mathematically trivial.)

All I know so far is the following very easy fact: There is a one-to-one correspondence between the subgroups of $PSL(2,Z)$ and the subgroups of $SL(2,Z)$ that contain −1. (I also know that from the point of view of computational group theory, it is perfectly possible for a computer to generate the normal subgroups of $SL(2,Z)$ or $PSL(2,Z)$, but I do not have a good understanding.)

Comment: I suspect  that it is not possible to answer this question in any sensible form. What exactly do you mean by "getting the normal subgroups" anyway? The group ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is an amalgamated free product of cyclic groups of orders $4$ and $6$ and is virtually free. It has infinitely many normal subgroups, many of which don't contain $-I_2$, and I doubt whether it is possible to give a coherent description of all of them. People tend to restrict attention to normal subgoups with specific additional properties.

Comment: @DerekHolt I interpret the question as if $H$ is a normal subgroup containing $-I$ then how to count and generate the normal subgroups such that $H=N\times \pm I$

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much for your professional answer. Maybe I should restrict my question to be more specific, for example, we know that $PSL(2,Z)$ has principal congruence subgroups $\Gamma(N)$ and $G_{k,m}$ (and so on) as its normal subgroups. So what I want to know is all the preimages of these groups in $SL(2,Z)$ (obviously a mapping from one to many). Note that $G_{k,m}$ is defined as the normal closure $Ncl(T^{mk},ST^{k}ST^{−k})$ in $PSL(2,Z) $(see [M.Newman 1967](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1994453) )

Comment: Perhaps you should ask that as a new more specific question. I don' know the answer.